# How come I can't see my bones in orthographic view?

Tags: rigging, bones, orthographic

i'm trying to model a rig using x mirror but I can't see the bones even though i'm in editmode. i want to extrude a bone on x axis so that two bones extrue using x-mirror. it donest work in persp view and in tutorials they use ortho view.

Comment: Adding screen shots or attaching .blend file will help you get more accurate answers

Comment: please attach a .blend file

Answer (score 1):

x-mirror is not view dependent, and is dependent on the bone names (i.e. ending with .L, .R) 
+1 screenshots or .blend